# Sorting of array with NaN element remain intact at its position

Tags: matlab, sorting

I have an array and want to sort it with `NaN` being intact at their place.

---

for eg:

`B=[5,2,NaN,NaN,9,34,23,NaN,89];`

the output should be:

```
B_sorted=[2,5,NaN,NaN,9,23,34,NaN,89];
```

Comment: So? Change your sorting method so it process NaNs in special way.

Comment: What programming language?

Comment: i'm doing it in matlab

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple solution is to do it in-place and not touch elements that are NaN

```
B=[5,2,NaN,NaN,9,34,23,NaN,89];
B(~isnan(B)) = sort(B(~isnan(B)))
```

or with a new array:

```
B_sorted = nan(size(B));
B_sorted(~isnan(B)) = sort(B(~isnan(B)))
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're doing this in Ruby...

```
b=[5,2,'NaN','NaN',9,34,23,'NaN',89]

b_sort = (b - ['NaN']).sort
b = b.map{|x| x == 'NaN' ? 'NaN' : b_sort.shift}
```

Answer (score -1):

Just sorting with a different compare method won't work, even if you define compare(x, NaN)=0 for every x. Both merge sort and quicksort will move your NaN's, I think.

I think you need to filter the not-NaN values, sort these, and overwrite the non-NaN indices.

In pseudo-code

```
int j = 0;
for(int i= 0; i <= B.size(); ++i)
  if(B[i] != NaN)
     indices[j] = i
     values[j] = B[i]
     ++j

sort(values[0 .. j-1])

for(int k = 0; k < j; ++k)
  B[indices[k]]=values[k]
```